# Arrange numbers to the equations, so if we turn the equations upside down, they are still right

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

[image: 851, 1091, 1101, 1181, 1501, 1801, 1901, 1998, 2652, 2822, 2982, 9512]

_ + _ = _ 
_ + _ = _ 
_ + _ = _ 
_ + _ = _

Fill the blanks with numbers above, so:

- The 4 additions are right.
- All numbers must be used.
- If we turn the additions upside down, they are still right, so there are 8 additions.
- You can rotate any numbers too, example 1091  ->  1601.

Comment: how to interpret 150 when reversed? 51?

Comment: It must be 1501, I will replace the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the equations are:

> ```
>  851 + 8661 = 9512
>  158 + 1998 = 2156
>
> 1091 + 1501 = 2592
> 1601 + 1051 = 2652
>
> 1801 + 1061 = 2862
> 1081 + 1901 = 2982
>
> 1101 + 1181 = 2282
> 1011 + 1811 = 2822
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer

> 2822 -> 2282
>   1181 + 1101 = 2282
>   2822 = 1011 + 1811
>
>   1901 -> 1061
>   2982 -> 2862
>   1801 + 1061 = 2862
>   2982 = 1901 + 1081
>
>   2652 -> 2592
>   1501 + 1091 = 2592
>   2652 = 1051 + 1601
>
>   1998->8661
>   8661 + 815 = 9512
>   2156 = 518 + 1998